# I am having trouble trying to put my buttons next to my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, button, navigation, positioning

first post and relatively new to programming, I am having trouble with trying to get my buttons further up the page and next to my side navigation bar, please view [picture](http://gyazo.com/42cd56ba529632889f8ba358e58608a5.png) and code:

HTML:

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
               <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li> <a href="news.html">News</a></li>
               <li> <a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
               <li> <a href="galleries.html">Galleries</a></li>
               <li> <a href="videos.html">Videos </a></li>
               <li> <a href="history.html">History</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
           </ul>    
      </nav>    



      <a id="bigthumbnailone" href="news.html">New Website Launched!</a>          
      <a id="bigthumbnailtwo" href="news.html">Next Major: i49 </a>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
  }

  a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color:#0099FF;
  }

  a:hover {
color:#0066FF;
font-weight:bold;
   }

  a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
color:#0099FF;
   }


  nav ul li {
display:;
margin:1px;
padding:30px;
list-style-type: none;
font-family:Segoe UI Light;
font-size:30px;
  }


 /*end navigation*/

 #bigthumbnailone {
display:block;
width:600px;
height:300px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:left;
font-family:Segoe UI Light;
font-size:25px;
background-image:url(../images/thumbnails/messi.png);
outline-style:solid;
outline-color:#0099FF;
margin: 0 auto;
 }

  #bigthumbnailtwo {
display:block;
width:600px;
height:300px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:left;
font-family:Segoe UI Light;
font-size:25px;
background-image:url(../images/thumbnails/messi.png);
outline-style:solid;
outline-color:#0099FF;
margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

What will I need to add to make sure my navigation bar and buttons can both be next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a div around your buttons, and then float: left your nav and the div that surrounds the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `display:inline-block;` like so:

```
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1px;
    padding:30px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family:Segoe UI Light;
    font-size:30px;
}

 #bigthumbnailone, #bigthumbnailtwo {
    display:inline-block;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Segoe UI Light;
    font-size:25px;
    background-image:url(../images/thumbnails/messi.png);
    outline-style:solid;
    outline-color:#0099FF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and place your thumbnails inside your unordered list like so:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="news.html">News</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="events.html">Events</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="galleries.html">Galleries</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="videos.html">Videos </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="history.html">History</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a>

        </li> <a id="bigthumbnailone" href="news.html">New Website Launched!</a>  <a id="bigthumbnailtwo" href="news.html">Next Major: i49 </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/btsPq/4/)

[MDN documentation for display and display values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)